# When is claims based identity not the correct answer?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, claims-based-identity, claims

I'm currently contracting with a company that is making architectural decisions for a suite of new multi-tenant applications.  Another contractor is adamant that we should be using claims-based identity.  I know it's the hot thing to do now, but given the client's scenario, I'm not comfortable affirming his proposal.

The applications will be service oriented, built on the .NET stack, and rely heavily on ASP.NET Web API.  The client apps (Web, Mobile, and WPF) will be fairly dumb, consuming the Web API services for business rules/functionality.

A subset of the services will be treated as a separate product offering and will be exposed for consumption by the company's business partners.

The applications will be offered as both a hosted solution and an on-premise solution since some of their customers want to host everything themselves and may not even have internet access.

Each "tenant", whether on the hosted solution or using the on-prem solution will be responsible for maintaining their user accounts, security groups, and group membership.

For the on-premise solution, we can not assume the host location will have Active Directory or any other infrastructure in place.  Actually, we should assume they have nothing other than what we give them.

I understand the concepts behind claims-based identity, but I don't see the benefit in a scenario such as this.  The client does not (and will never) want users to login with an Id from Facebook, Google, etc.  Each user will login with their email address, which could be anything from a gmail account to MomAndPopsEmailDomain.com email address.

To make this work using claims, wouldn't we essentially have to build an STS for the company that could be used for their hosting solution and also distributed with any on-premise installations for stand-alone use?  If so, what benefit is this over just rolling our own membership/identity provider that authenticates a user and generates the user's authorization token (group membership info)?

Do claims make it easier when authenticating against the WebAPI services?

Answer (score 1):

Claims based authentication is fine, but from what you described, it's probably not the best option for that scenario because it will paint you into a corner if requirements change. Personally, I would use OAuth 2.0 with my own OAuth security service (which can be apart of the existing web api) because it's more of a standard when working with mobile apps that you don't have control over and it sets up your system to be able to maintain usernames and passwords.

You said the client apps maintain the username and passwords. So, I would have an OAuth security service that hands out a bearer token with a refresh token. The client app would be given an api key which your system would maintain, and when they request a token they would need to provide that api key, which you would validate and send back a token. From there the client would send that token in the http header with every request. When the token expires the refresh token can be used to get a new one.

If the requirements change to where your system needs to maintain the username and passwords, you just modify the OAuth token server to authenticate/Authorize users in addition to api keys. Then, for users with passwords, the OAuth security service would have a redirect address to a login page that the client would display and the end user would log in into it. That way the client apps never see the username and password.

Here's a good video on it - http://vimeo.com/user22258446/review/79095048/9a4d62f61c

Here's a sample of how to implement the bearer token. Open the project in  Thinktecture.IdentityModel / samples / OAuth2 / EmbeddedResourceOwnerFlowWithRefreshTokens / EmbeddedAuthorizationServer - https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityModel

I hope that helps.